# remove sample from anndata .obs and .x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can see how to remove columns from anndata ie

`keep = ['a','b','c']`

`adata = adata [:, keep]`

How does one remove rows from `anndata.obs` and `anndata.x`?

for example remove `adata.obs[Region='reg012']`

Dataframe `adata.obs`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove row if `Region` contians `reg012` then..

Assuming `Data Frame = adata.obs`

```
adata.obs= adata.obs[~adata.obs.Region.str.contains("reg012")]
```